# Z-Transform of a^|n|

Tags: z-transform

I am wanting to compute the Z-transform of $f(n) = a^{|n|}$ . 'a' is a positive constant.

Looking at the transform table, I found that Z-transform for $a^n u(n)$
is available from the tables and is $\frac{Z}{Z-a}$. Where $u(n)$ is the unit step function.

I am trying to decompose $f(n)$ as --
$f(n) = a^n u(n)  +  a^{-n} u(-n) + \delta(n)$

Then using the table to find $Z( f(n) )$ as --
$\frac{Z}{Z-a} + \frac{Z^{-1}}{Z^{-1} - a} + 1$

Can anyone tell me if this approach is correct and/or suggest an alternate way. 
Thanks!

Comment: For comparison: [Wolfram Alpha: Z transform of a^|n|](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Z+transform+of+a%5E%7Cn%7C)

Comment: Don't think you need $\delta(n)$ in your decomposition.

Comment: As per wolfram the z-transform is $\frac{z}{z-a}$. Is this same as ignoring the negative part ie. when n is negative. Please help about how this comes up.

Comment: Wolfram's Z-Transform is [one-sided/unilateral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/UnilateralZ-Transform.html).  Here's the two-sided/bilateral Z-Transform sum calculated directly: [Sum\[a^|n| * z^(-n), n from -infinity to +infinity\]](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5Ba%5E%7Cn%7C+*+z%5E%28-n%29%2C+n+from+-infinity+to+%2Binfinity%5D)

Comment: I think you are decomposing properly but replace delta[n] by -delta[n] in f[n] equation. Just check for n=0 if you are unsure
.

Comment: For any z transform of a^n it is just n/(n-a)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the right way to decompose this function is:

$f(n) = a^n u(n)  +  a^{-n} u(-n)$

Then the answer for your question is:

$Z( f(n) ) = \frac{Z}{Z-a} + \frac{Z^{-1}}{Z^{-1} - a}$
EDIT: Looks like it is wrong answer. :(

---

Ok, let's start from the beggining and try to find right answer step by step

Given sequence is $f(n) = a^{|n|}$ . 'a' is a positive constant.$

1) Let's  decompose it into sum of 2 sequences:

$f(n) = a^n u(n)  +  a^{-n} u(-n-1)$

2) If we define $f_1(n) = a^n u(n)$  and $f_2(n) = a^{-n} u(-n-1)$
Then $Z( f(n) ) = Z( f_1(n) )+Z( f_2(n) )$

---

3) $Z( f_1(n) ) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} a^n u(n) z^{-n} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (az^{-1})^n = \frac{1}{1-az^{-1}} = \frac{z}{z-a}  $

---

4) $Z( f_2(n) ) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}  a^{-n} u(-n-1) z^{-n} = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1} (az)^{-n} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (az)^{n} = -1+1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (az)^{n} = -1+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (az)^{n} = -1 + \frac{1}{1-az} = \frac{-1+az+1}{1-az} = \frac{az}{1-az} $

---

5) $Z( f(n) ) = Z( f_1(n) )+Z( f_2(n) ) = \frac{z}{z-a} + \frac{az}{1-az} = \frac{z}{z-a} - \frac{z}{z-\frac{1}{a}} $

If there is anything unclear or wrong in this derivation, please comment.

As for wolfram answer - I don't know why it is so. I never used wolfram before. 
But it perfoms symbolic computations and you must be sure that your assumptions about range of n (does $n\in[-\infty,\infty]$  or $ n\in[0,\infty]$ ) for example should coinside with wolfram assumptions.

Comment: I believe this answer is not consistent with what we get with wolfram http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Z+transform+of+a%5E%7Cn%7C

Can someone also explain why this discrepancy?

Comment: Ok, I edited original answer and put detailed derivation in it.

Comment: @casador, I'm wondering whether the $f_2(n)$ in the above answer should be $a^{−n-1}u[−n−1]$?
then can we use property of folding and time-shift to find the z-transform? $f_2(n)=a^{-n-1}u[-n-1]=a^{-(n+1)}u[-(n+1)] \xrightarrow{z-transform\ with \ fold\ and\ shift } z^{-(-1)}F(1/z)=zF(1/z)=z\frac{1}{1-az^{-(-1)}}=\frac{z}{1-az}$